# Julia - Get HTML from url

Tags: julia

Is there a way to request an URL and get the response as a string?

I've tried to use both the "Requests" package and "LibCURL" but I cant find a way to do this

Fx. if I use requests the error I receive looks like

```
get(url)
ERROR: MbedTLS error code -30592: SSL - A fatal alert message was received from     our peer
 in macro expansion at /home/david/.julia/v0.5/MbedTLS/src/error.jl:4 [inlined]
 in handshake(::MbedTLS.SSLContext) at /home/david/.julia/v0.5/MbedTLS/src/    ssl.jl:145
 in open_stream(::HttpCommon.Request, ::MbedTLS.SSLConfig, ::Float64, ::Nullable{URIParser.URI}, ::Nullable{URIParser.URI}) at /home/david/.julia/    v0.5/Requests/src/streaming.jl:209
 in #do_stream_request#23(::Dict{AbstractString,AbstractString}, ::Void, ::Void, ::Void, ::Array{Requests.FileParam,1}, ::Void, ::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{HttpCommon.Response,1}, ::MbedTLS.SSLConfig, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Nullable{URIParser.URI}, ::Nullable{URIParser.URI}, ::Requests.#do_stream_request, ::URIParser.URI, ::String) at /home/david/.julia    /v0.5/Requests/src/Requests.jl:361
 in do_stream_request(::URIParser.URI, ::String) at /home/david/.julia/v0.5/    Requests/src/Requests.jl:324
 in #do_request#22(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::URIParser.URI, ::String) at /    home/david/.julia/v0.5/Requests/src/Requests.jl:291
 in #get#29(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::URIParser.URI) at /home/david/.julia/    v0.5/Requests/src/Requests.jl:424
 in #get#28(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::String) at /home/david/.julia/v0.5/    Requests/src/Requests.jl:423
 in get(::String) at /home/david/.julia/v0.5/Requests/src/Requests.jl:423
```

Comment: Your edit just drastically changed your question.  You're not interested in getting the response as a string… because you're not getting any response at all! You'll need to post more context if you'd like help debugging that error.  Can you reproduce it on a publicly available website?  E.g., `https://example.com` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `readall` with Requests (but in the future it may be moved to [`readstring`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/io-network.html#Base.readstring) since `readall` has been deprecated in Base Julia):

```
julia> using Requests

julia> readall(get("http://example.com"))
"<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head> …
```